# HTML anchor combined with attributes class and name and no content (HTML4)

Tags: html

I received responsibility for a huge documentation from my client (several thousands html files, some programs or scripts to generate pages out of database etc.).

In a group of files belonging to the same chapter I find the following

```
<a name="Suchfeld">Suchfeld</a><a class="Schlagwort" name="Suchfeld_Definition"></a>
```

The first anchor is nothing special (Suchfeld describes a string which is used to search in an application).

The second one surprises with a class-attribute (it seems to be allowed there: My HTML checker does not complain). There is no entry for Schlagwort in the central CSS file (Schlagwort means in German something like keyword and is used to create an index). And the anchor itself is empty.

Does anybody have an idea why this construction is used? Could it be some failed attempt to prepare the collection of documents to have an index ready? I think I could delete these code fragments but I'm not sure. I have also searched the whole filesystem on "Schlagwort" or "Suchfeld" (also scripts), but only files with the explained construction are hit.

More detailed examples (added later):

```
   <dt>
    <a name="Suchfeld">Suchfeld</a><a class="Schlagwort" name="Suchfeld_Definition"></a>
   </dt>
   <dd>
     some text
   </dd>
```

or

```
<h2>OPTION</h2>
<a class="Schlagwort" name="Suchbegriffstyp_OPTION"></a>
<hr>
<table ...>
...
</table>
```

or

```
<h2>Vergleich der Ergebnisse <a class="Schlagwort" name="Vergleich"></a></h2>
```

Added comment:

```
name"Suchfeld"
```

was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class attribute to pretty much any HTML tag. If it's stylable, you can create a class to add CSS. You can also assign a class to an element even if the class is not defined.

The 1st a tag should be name="#Suchfeld" if they are using it as a "bookmark" or "anchor", not name"Suchfeld". See here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp